# Do adjectives still need to agree with a noun if they are in a subsequent clause without a verb?

Tags: english-to-german, adjective, grammaticality, apposition

This question has to do with when adjectives have to be treated as attributive (i.e. they would need to agree with the noun) or predicate (they would not need to agree).

I want to translate part of an English sentence:

> ... the basis of all life, personal as well as collective, ...

This is saying that something forms the basis of all life, personal as well as collective (community or social) life.

In German I currently have it as

> ... die Basis des ganzen Lebens, sowohl persönlich als auch kollektiv ...

*Persönlich* and *kollektiv* are not positioned before the verb like attributive adjectives, but rather in the kind of position I would expect for predicative adjectives, with a verb like so:

> ... das sowohl persönlich als auch kollektiv ist ...

So I am not sure how to treat them.

I am actually not even sure if this type of thing (the short clarifying clause without a verb, which is normal in English) is grammatical in German, or if I need to just rewrite it to have a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*... the basis of all life, personal as well as collective ...*

> ... die Basis des ganzen Lebens, sowohl persönlich als auch kollektiv ...

is both straightforward and correct. German as well as English do not require verb phrases here. In German, this even extends to stray adjectives/adverbs and participles:

> Der Sekretär des Königs, **altgedient** *[wie er war]*, verzog keine Miene.
>
> Die Blumenkästen, **farbenfroh** *[wie sie waren]*, **duftend** *[wie sie waren]*, machten die zuvor so schäbige Gasse zu einem Kleinod.

Answer (score 1):

> .. die Basis des ganzen Lebens, sowohl persönlich als auch kollektiv ...

This sentence is valid German, but here I would understand "persönlich" and "kollektiv" as adverbs rather than adjectives.

If you want to leave no doubt about them being adjectives, it has to be:

> .. die Basis des ganzen Lebens, sowohl des persönlichen als auch des kollektiven ...

So there is some (potential) difference in meaning. In the first translation, the sentence can be understood as being about the base of life in both personal and collective respect. In the second, it's clearly about the base of personal and collective life.